# Actualizar un dato desde la funcion update del controlador de una tabla relacionada en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validación, laravel-blade, laravel-10

Tengo una tabla llamada "registros", que está relacionada con la tabla "equipos". En "equipos" agregué un dato llamado "availability" de tipo smallint y lo pasé como un "1" de manera predeterminada cada que se agrega un nuevo equipo.
El caso es que en el controlador de registros, tengo, en la función "index", una consulta con la cual filtro por medio del dato "availability" los equipos que se muestran en el select dentro de mi formulario de registro.

La siguiente es la consulta con la que rescato la información de mi equipo, para poder llamarla dentro del select dedicado a equipos en mi formulario de creación de registros:

```
    $equipos = DB::table('equipos as e')
        ->join('sistemasoperativos as so','so.soid','=','e.soid')
        ->join('modelos as m','m.modeloid','=','e.modeloid')
        ->join('marcas as ma','ma.marcaid','=','m.marcaid')
        ->select('e.equipoid',
             'e.evidenciafrontal',
             'e.evidencialateral',
             'e.evidenciatrasera',
             'e.nni',
             'e.serie',
             'e.usuariodom',
             'e.hostname',
             'e.ip',
             'e.mac',
             'e.availability',
             'so.soid',
             'so.nombreso',
             'm.modeloid',
             'm.nombremodelo',
             'ma.nombremarca')
        ->where('e.availability','=','1')
        ->get();
```

este es mi formulario de creacion de registros (al menos solo el select que me interesa):

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="create" tabindex="-1" aria- 
    labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="exampleModalLabel"></h1>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>

            <form action="{{ route('crear-registro') }}" method="post">
                @csrf
                <div class="modal-body">

                    <div class="row text-lg-start text-sm-start">

                        {{-- equipo input --}}
                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="mb-1">
                                <label for="" class="form-label text- 
                                success">Equipo</label>
                                <select class="form-control form-select" name="equipo" 
                                id="">
                                    <option selected> Selecciona un equipo </option>
                                    @foreach ($equipos as $e)
                                        <option value="{{ $e->equipoid }}">
                                            NNI: {{ $e->nni }} - 
                                            MODELO: "{{ $e->nombremarca }}
                                            {{ $e->nombremodelo}}"
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-bs- 
                        dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Lo que busco es que cada registro tenga su propio equipo, entonces paso un "update" en mis funciones "store" y "destroy" para que cambie el valor de availability de 1 a 0 y así no permitir que se pueda ver dentro de mi select, por ejemplo así funciona en mi función store:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $registros=new Registro;
    $registros->equipoid=$request->input('equipo');
    $registros->responsableid=$request->input('responsable');
    $registros->oficinaid=$request->input('oficina');
    
    DB::table('equipos')
    ->where('equipoid','=',$registros->equipoid)
    ->update(['availability' => '0']);

    $registros->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Mi problema es que no sé como actualizar availability dentro de mi función update, ya que, al pasar el "update(['availability' => '0'])" si cambia el valor de "availability" del nuevo equipo seleccionado, pero deja al anterior equipo con el valor 0 que ya había actualizado en el store y quiero que el dato availability de este pase a ser 1 en lugar de 0.
¿qué puedo hacer para resolver esto? Es lo único que me falta para terminar mi proyecto.

Comment: No sé mucho de laravel pero he mirado un par de ejemplos y creo que a partir del argumento que recibes en la función update puedes recuperar el registro a actualizar, y de ahí sacar el id del equipo que quieres poner a 1, no? Usando una expresión similar a la que ya tienes para poner a cero. Sería 1) Recupero registro a actualizar; 2) Recupero id equipo actual; 3) Pongo a 1 equipo actual; 4) Actualizo registro; 5) Pongo a 0 equipo nuevo.

Comment: Si lo consigues, puedes responder tú mismo la pregunta con tu nuevo método update

Comment: Podrías compartir el ejemplo? Así podría entenderlo más gráficamente

Comment: https://dev.to/jackmiras/laravel-update-actions-simplified-1djp

Answer (score 0):

Después de asesorarme con un profesor en Laravel lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

```
$equipos = DB::table('equipos as e')
    ->join('sistemasoperativos as so','so.soid','=','e.soid')
    ->join('modelos as m','m.modeloid','=','e.modeloid')
    ->join('marcas as ma','ma.marcaid','=','m.marcaid')
    ->select('e.equipoid',
         'e.evidenciafrontal',
         'e.evidencialateral',
         'e.evidenciatrasera',
         'e.nni',
         'e.serie',
         'e.usuariodom',
         'e.hostname',
         'e.ip',
         'e.mac',
         'e.availability',
         'so.soid',
         'so.nombreso',
         'm.modeloid',
         'm.nombremodelo',
         'ma.nombremarca')
    ->get();
```

Quité el where de mi consulta general y mejor filtré la información desde mi front, este es mi select de equipos en la creacion de registros ahora:

```
{{-- equipo input --}}
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="mb-1">
      <label for="" class="form-label text-success">Equipo</label>
      <select class="form-control form-select" name="equipo" id="">
      <option selected> Selecciona un equipo </option>
        @foreach ($equipos as $e)
          @if($e->availability == 1)
          {
          <option value="{{ $e->equipoid }}">
          NNI: {{ $e->nni }} -
          MODELO: "{{ $e->nombremarca }} {{ $e->nombremodelo }}"
          </option>
          } @endif
        @endforeach
     </select>
   </div>
  </div>
```

y así quedó mi select de equipos en la edición de registros:

```
{{-- equipo input --}}
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="mb-1">
     <label for="" class="form-label text-success">Equipo</label>
     <select class="form-control form-select" name="equipo" id="">
        @foreach ($equipos as $e)
          @if ($q->equipoid == $e->equipoid)
          <option value="{{ $e->equipoid }}" selected required>
          NNI: {{ $e->nni }} -
          MODELO: "{{ $e->nombremarca }} {{ $e->nombremodelo }}"
          </option>
          @else
          @if ($e->availability != 0)
          {
          <option value="{{ $e->equipoid }}">
          NNI: {{ $e->nni }} -
          MODELO: "{{ $e->nombremarca }} {{ $e->nombremodelo }}"
          </option>
          }
          @endif
          @endif
          @endforeach
          </select>
          <input type="hidden" class="form-control"
          name="equipoanterior" id="" aria-describedby="helpId" 
          placeholder="" value="{{ $q->equipoid }}">
  </div>
</div>
```

El input de tipo "hidden" es para guardar el id del anterior equipo, por medio de él es que puedo cambiar mi dato de tipo "availability" que estaba en 0 y cambiarlo a 1. En cambio, el equipoid de mi select lo uso para cambiar su dato "availability" de 1 a 0.

No sé si es la mejor opción para resolver mi problema, pero a esa conclusión llegué con la asesoría de mi profesor.